Don't bump "dead" questions
Community Bot visits old questions and bumps them so that they can receive answers and hopefully have an accepted answer eventually.
However, many answers are old, and the OP sometimes hasn’t visited the site in years. It is therefore very unlikely they will see any new answer, let alone accept one.
Is there any way to reprogram Community Bot so that this kind of thing doesn’t happen anymore? I find it very annoying to see “dead” questions bumped by Community Bot…

Answers are not for OP but for literally everybody who visits the question. This isn't a helpdesk, we don't do individual help - any question is here to help future visitors, so they don't have to ask it but directly find the answers.

Answers don't only exist to help the OP, but also others who find the question when they are looking for a solution to their problem that looks similar. Therefore, posting an answer to an old question is still beneficial.
Once a question has an answer with a nonzero score, the Community bot will stop bumping the question.

Oh, OK, I thought Community Bot was only bumping questions that had no accepted answers.
